Andoird gradle build
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Rohit Ritu\my_pal\android\build.gradle' line: 4

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.



Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
please help me out to resolve this issues.

Please share you build.gradle file contents.
